# How can I regex a string that is written so far in command output?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm setting up a terminating step upon finding ExitCode=1 or greater via regex, in the **same** PowerShell script.

I will upload this in a jenkins job where there are running other 3rd party softwares that return Lastexitcode which Powershell doesn't recognize them so I need a function with regex to find in what is written so far and terminate upon finding it.

I tried:

```
[regex]::new('ExitCode=[1-9]*[0-9]')
```

```
function script:ThrowErrors {
  if ([regex]::new('ExitCode=[1-9]*[0-9]') {
    'erorrrrr'
  }
  if ($env:Terminating -eq 1) {
    throw 'This error is terminating the step.'
  }
}

# ps1 log with steps and written output
# step one
1+2 

'ExitCode=1'
'ExitCode=0'
'ExitCode=10'
$env:Terminating = '1'

ThrowErrors

# step two
2+3
```

I expect upon running the function, it will find the indicated regex formula in the whole script and terminate the step, but instead I reach the second step and the bug is that it doesn't find nothing in the first place.

Comment: You create a regex object, but you never do anything with it. A regular expression will not magically apply itself, and it particularly won't retroactively apply itself to output that came and went before the object was even created. Please provide more information about what output you're getting, and where it's coming from.

Comment: hi @AnsgarWiechers, I almost know nothing about what you mentioned. To try to explain: I have a jenkins job that runs multiple powershell scripts. 1.ps1, 2.ps1, 3.ps1 etc. And at some point one of the scripts is running that ThrowError function. I need help so that function looks troughout what it is writen so far by other scripts (in Jenkins Console Output) and terminate.

Comment: i need to use regex somehow to find ExitCode=1 or greater in what is written so far in the .ps1.

Comment: Like I said, you cannot retroactively apply a regular expression to output that was written before. If you have the output in a logfile you could parse that logfile.

Comment: Alright, i understand, is there a posibility to have all that was written so far in a logfile and checked for regex(ErrorCode), then continue the script in the same .ps1?

Comment: Probably, but that would depend on how your Jenkins and the jobs are configured.

Comment: the thing is i am running 3rd party like UnrealEngine4, and powershell doesn't recognize its LastExitCode and will continue to next script and such. Instead I want it to terminate there upon having a check for "ExitCode=1+" and if not continue the script.

Comment: You'd have to provide a *lot* more information about your environment, the Jenkins configuration, and the jobs run by Jenkins, for people to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think so the variable `$env:Terminating` is all the time empty. The following works for me:

```
function script:ThrowErrors {
  if ([regex]::new('ExitCode=[1-9]*[0-9]'))
  {
    'erorrrrr'
  }
  if ($env:Terminating -eq 1) {
    throw 'This error is terminating the step.'
  }
}

robocopy.exe ? | Out-Null
$env:Terminating = $LASTEXITCODE
$env:Terminating
ThrowErrors

PS C:\> ThrowErrors
erorrrrr
```

Comment: thank you @Patrick, for the reply. But it isn't what I am looking for.I need it to check if is written somewhere ErrorCode=1 or greater instead of checking the $Lasexitcode and terminate at that line.
```function script:ThrowErrors {
  if ([regex]::new('ExitCode=[1-9]*[0-9]'))
  {
    'Error'
    'Stop here please'
  }
  if ($env:Terminating -eq 1) {
    throw 'Terminating'
  }
}

robocopy.exe ? | Out-Null
$env:Terminating = $LASTEXITCODE
$env:Terminating

'ExitCode=0'
ThrowErrors
'ExitCode=1'
ThrowErrors
'Nah I continue'
```
if you run this the output will look like this

Comment: ```16

ExitCode=1

ExitCode=0
error
Stop here please
Nah I continue
```

Comment: Using `[regex]::new('ExitCode=[1-9]*[0-9]')` as a conditional is pointless, because (a) it doesn't test against any input and (b) it is _always true_.

Answer (score 0):

````
# Global enviroment variable
$env:Terminating = '0'


#Checks for ErrorCode value that has more than 0
#Checks for Terminating value


function script:CheckErrors 
{
  Get-Content -Path Step.log | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $CurrentErrorCode = $_

    switch -regex ($CurrentErrorCode) 
    {
      'ExitCode=[1-9][0-9]?' 
      {
        'Found a high error code'
        if ($Terminating -eq 1) 
        {
          'Terminating is enabled.'
          throw 'Terminated'
        }
        else
        {
          'Terminating is disabled.'
        }
      }
      'ExitCode=0'                
      {

      }
    }
  }
}


# All bellow steps can have parts of build scripts.
# Fake step with no errors.
function script:Step1 
{
  'Running Step1'
  "This step hasn't any errors"
  '1/1'
  1/1
  'ExitCode=0'
}

# Another step that has an error but it won't be terminating.
function script:Step2 
{
  'Running Step2'
  'This step has a non terminating error'
  '1/0'
  1/0
  'ExitCode=1'
}

# Another step that has an error but this time is terminating.
function script:Step3 
{
  'Running Step3'
  'This step has a terminating error'
  '1/0'
  1/0
  'ExitCode=10'
}

# This step is in case of the terminating step is bugged.
function script:Step4 
{
  'Running Step4'
  'End of the process.' 
}


# The actual steps.
# Jenkins job will look like this.

#Set-Location "D:\Build_scripts"
#.\NewErrorHandling.ps1


''
Step1 | Tee-Object -FilePath Step.log
$Terminating = '0'
CheckErrors
''
''
Step2 | Tee-Object -FilePath Step.log
$Terminating = '0'
CheckErrors
''
''
Step3 | Tee-Object -FilePath Step.log
$Terminating = '1'
CheckErrors
''
''
Step4 | Tee-Object -FilePath Step.log
$Terminating = '0'
CheckErrors
''
''

# Cleaner if you use ISE.
$Error.Clear()```
````

Comment: this is what i wanted,
thank you all for the help provided.

Comment: Your answer has no obvious connection to your question (and future readers shouldn't have to read through lengthy comment exchanges to glean additional information). Where does `Step.log` come from? Where is `$Terminating` defined? Did you mean `$env:Terminating`? As an aside: you can directly make `switch` iterate over all lines in a file with the `-File` option - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch